# jQuery UI upgrade creates tooltip position problem. Is there any problem with .position() in jQuery 1.12.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have recently upgraded jQuery Ui from 1.10.1 to 1.12.1 and it changes my tooltip placement. IT use to place at left bottom of the element but now after upgrade it appears at left top. Any reason? Is position() in jQuery changed?

It works fine when I use .position() function from older version (1.10.4). Is it fine to have jquery ui 1.12.1 with a .position() function override?

Comment: did you update css too ?

Comment: Paste the code that you have tried. It will be useful to debug.

Comment: @Taylor Rahul Sorry. What css I need to update? I haven't changed css.

Comment: Just like jQuery UI .. it provide you a package of JS And CSS both .. it seems like you just updated the JS File .. not the CSS file . please update this too

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css ..

Comment: please cross with your JS version and pick the correct one

Comment: In my existing code the css is customized and added in projects main css file. So do you know specific classes or css to check for tooltip and position problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest jQuery has .position() function definition is changed. So I have managed to position the tooltip using position configuration while using rendering Tooltip(...,position,...);

Comment: Hey, could you please describe more about what solution you had to do? I have the same problem now and i'm not exactly understand your answer :X